# How to detect the installation and start MySQL server automatically from an application built in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, process.start

I am developing a C# desktop application for my client that uses MySQL Server. What my client demands is that the database server should be started at the time of application start and also it should be stopped at the application exit. I know how to start a process in C# using Process.Start() but what I don't know is that how to **detect the installation path of the MySQL server and start the server** because the condition of my client is that the server installation path may change in future. Also I don't know **how to stop a process/service in C#**. So please tell me these two things:

- Detect installation path of MySQL and start the server via C#
- Stop the MySQL server on application exit via C#

I tried this but this code needs the path of the MySql installation. I need the path automatic and I am unable to predict any code for that

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("mysqld.exe") == null)
{
    Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Cluster 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe");
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything on your own ?

Comment: How you stop process in task manager?...by [killing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) it

Comment: Yes @Nacereddine I edited my question see it

Comment: OLEDB connections would be suitable for you in such cases or use SQL Server 2008 r2...why to start it each time and close it???

Comment: @freelancer: I don't no why they need it I also said to them, but they say due to some security reasons we have to do this

Comment: have you seen regarding this issue whatever answer i have posted??plz tell me so that further things can be done...and if u have came to know the real answer then please post it...so that i wil also come to know...its really a good question and i m upvoting it...

Answer (score 0):

Give path for MySQLInstanceConfig.exe in the bin folder...

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld"

Go through following link which may help you

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-config-wizard-starting.html

Answer (score 0):

> This works perfectly....
> Just go to your windows services and determine the service name for the MySQL instance on the machine.
> Mine is 'MySQL57'. The time out is just to ensure the service state returns the expected value before doing other things.

```
    public int RestartMySQL()
    {
        var serviceName = "MySQL57";
        var timeoutMilliseconds = 2000;

        var service = new ServiceController(serviceName, Environment.MachineName);

        try
        {
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

            if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
            }

            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);

            return 5;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```